# How can I determine the direction to get from point p1 to p2 in a 2D array map?

Tags: arrays, maps, 2d

in a given 2 points (p1,p2) and the assumption they are next to each other (can be i the X line or Y line) how can you know the derection that need to be done to get from p1 to p2?

so the aswer is easy:
fisrt compere the x values if they are the same compere the y values and if p1.y is bigger then p2.y you need to go down and same if the x values not the same.

```
if(p1.x==p2.x){
   if(p1.y>p2.y){ down}
     else {up}
}
else // p1.x!=p2.x
{
if(p1.x>p2.x){ left}
else{ right}
}
```

this mathod good for maps based of 2D arry in many games.